# relocated MVC solution folder in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I create a MVC project in Visual Studio, it will automatically generate a solution folder with the same name alone with .sln file, packages folder.

For example:

/MyProject/MyProject

and when I run the application in server:

http://XXXXX/MyProject/MyProject

I hate the address. I want to the address looks like:

http://XXXXX/MyProject

I tried to move the solution folder to upper level directory, however, the MVC project can still run but show errors and many warnings.

Is there any way I can create a MVC and I can specify the solution folder? or I can relocate the MVC solution folder nicely?

Thanks

Comment: Is the "Create directory for solution" box checked?

Answer (score 0):

You can relocate sln file.

Just close solution, move sln file to project folder, and then open sln file in VS.
Project will not load. Delete unloaded project in Solution Explorer, then right click on solution (in Solution Explorer) Add => existing project...
and select .csproj file of the project.
Rebuild application, nuget will restore packeges.

But I don't know why You hate path. 
You can name solution folder with diffrent name then Your project. when You add more projects every project folder will be in one solution folder and path will looks like:
http://XXXXX/Solution/Project1
http://XXXXX/Solution/Project2

And one last thing: You probobly don't want whole solution in application server, you can just deploy project as web deploy packege.